# Grand total of top 10 in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on Tableau where I have to find the Grand Total of only Top 10 Parents.

I have a Real Estate DB with fields as Parent Name,monthly rent,annual rent per sq. feet,Square feet,etc.

I have to calculate 
1)the Annual Rent("Current ABR") using annual rent per sq. feet x unit square feet.
2) %ABR : Current ABR/Total ABR(Current ABR).
Note: The %ABR is calculated on Total ABR of all Parents(I have approx 560 parents)

My worksheet in tableau looks like this: [image]

How I have brought the Top 10 Parents is I have used the Index() method of tableau and given the index to all the tenants based on “Current ABR” descending sort. Now, I am using this index as a filter and showing the top 10 Parents which is giving the correct list and %ABR calculation is correct. But, when using “Grand Total”, it shows the total(Current & %ABR) of all the tenants rather than just the Top 10.

Also, the traditional method to filter the parent name “Top 10 by Sum of Monthly Rent” gives 2 issues where top 10 tenants are different and the %ABR calculation gives wrong result as it is calculated table down.

I need to find the Grand Total of ABR and %ABR of only Top 10 Parents.

Comment: use `WINDOW_SUM(SUM(CURRENT_ABR))` . Specify calculation as `table down` which is very important for it to work .

Comment: Thanks, but how should I put this new calculation onto the worksheet instead of grand total..

Comment: Same sheet it won't be possible as a new `row` . can be possible as new `column` .

Answer (score 1):

Create a field on Current ABR ->

```
top 10 = Index() < 10
```

Create another field ->

```
Top10Calc = if [top 10] 
sum([Current ABR])
else
Windows_sum([Current ABR]) end
```

Do your percentage calculations on top of this top10calc field.

And then create the report now your grand total should show correct values as top 10 are showing the values only for top 10 ABR and index filter is implicitly
taken care by calculations.

Answer (score 0):

First top 10 parents name to used the index() method .top 10 position requires identify in easy to tableau.which field you want to top  10 position in just put the **filter** in field and then Right click in to shown the **edit filter** and then select the **top** menu . just go to the **By field**  put the information to got the top 10 position.next you drag the columns .and then select **Analysis** menu to shown the **Grand totals** .

Answer (score 0):

Select/Highlight top 10 rows in the first column, right click and select "Keep Only".